# Count the number of outgoing calls (2.2 or above)

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-call, calllog

I need a snippet for counting the number of outgoing calls in Android.

All I want to do is something like this:

```
int num = getTheNumberOfOutgoingCalls(Context c);
```

Answer (score 2):

This [tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/video-tut_-_querying_and_displaying_the_calllog-t169.html) might help you. Edit the codes to suit your application needs.